# Creating note for iphone and ipad

Tags: iphone

I want to create a note (like iphone note)as a subview to a view-controller,my requirement is when the user tap the button the note have to appear in the screen.
How to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @robin i just tried to create a textview that the user can write note,but i didnt know how to save within the application,and also the user need to watch this note whnevr he wants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you save `nsobjects` in a plist.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"DetailsList" ofType:@"plist"];
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:path]];
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:textView.text, @"Note", [NSDate date], @"Current Date", nil];
[array addObject:dict];
NSString *error;
NSData *plistData = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataFromPropertyList:array
                                                               format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0
                                                     errorDescription:&error];
if(plistData)
{
    if([plistData writeToFile:path atomically:YES])
        NSLog(@"success");
    else
        NSLog(@"fail");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"%@ ", error);
    [error release];
}
```

And for more info. on this refer here http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPropertyListSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html